Blender Animation - Set Keyframes in Edit Mode with Simple Deform Modifier
I want to get an animation as shown here:
.
I already achieved the general look of the object with the Simple Deform Modifier.


I can achieve the desired animation effect when rotating the base object in edit mode around the z axis.
)
But as I found out, there is no real way to keyframe the rotation in edit mode. When rotating in object mode, the whole object rotates, which I don't want. Applying the modifiers didn't help either. Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks!

Since you made your shape with modifiers, the right way to make the animation is to have it happen before these two modifiers are computed. Which you intuitively understood, since you thought of trying to animate the mesh in edit mode, but that specific way isn't really available (some addons can help, but it's not the best to do anyway).
The greater solution would be to animate your object with an armature bound to your object via an armature deform modifier placed above your simple deform modifiers, effectively making the armature deform happen before the other modifiers
Assuming your object's origin is at its mesh center, let's snap your 3D cursor to your object by selecting it and pressing ⇧ Shift+S > Cursor to Selected.

In object mode, press Shift+A > Armature > Single Bone. It will spawn at the 3D cursor which is centered to your mesh.

Select your mesh object, then ⇧ Shift select your armature and press ⇧ Shift+P > Set parent to Armature Deform Modifier With Automatic Weights.

Select your mesh object. In the modifiers tab, drag the armature deform at the top of the pile.

To make sure the whole mesh is assigned to the bone, ↹ Tab into edit mode, select the whole mesh. Go to the mesh data tab > vertex groups panel, select the vertex group named after your bone and hit the assign button.

Once this is done, you can select the Armature object, ↹ Tab into Pose Mode.
Set the bone's rotation mode to XYZ Euler (the default quaternion is tricker to hand animate).

Then you can rotate the bone on its Y axis (or global Z, if you use the gizmo with Global Transform orientation as per default).

This can be keyed with I or right-clicking the Rotation input. You can even make an infinite rotation by writing #frame*.1 in the Y rotation input, which will make a driver using the scene's current frame multiplied by a factor. Change the factor to chose your desired rotation speed.


This was exactly what I was looking for and it worked as intended. Thank you! :)

Another possibility would be (even if you didn't explicitly ask for it) to solve this with Geometry Nodes.

Something like this:

Here I simply create a mesh from two circles (to be precise, two spirals whose starting and end points are in the same position).
First, I change the curve tilt of the first curve so that a twisted mesh is created at the end.
Then I correct the end points a little, because the normals are not pointing in the desired direction due to the use of a spiral, and create a UV map.
If you now want to process the whole thing with keyframes, simply replace the  Scene Time node with a setup of your choice or set your keyframes directly there.
(Blender 4.2.0+)

Thanks for this idea. I never touched the Geometry Nodes, but it looks interesting. I did however spot a little mistake in your version. The object doesn't close properly. (seem like I can't incluse a screenshot here...)
I did solve the problem with Lauloque's solution tho. :)
Thank you!

@WPWA You are welcome! Just out of interest, because I don't understand it at the moment: what do you mean by “it doesn't close properly”? PS: By the way, you can add an image to your question, copy the link, and cancel the edit. This way you can upload an image and link to it in the comments.

I hope the image link works: https://i.sstatic.net/8MGSJB3T.png

@WPWA Ah, I see. That's exactly why I'm using the Set Position node with Vector Rotate to align the two ends correctly. Just try it with the file (and Blender 4.2+) I have attached here. As you can see in my picture, it works perfectly.
